# Class methods as Pyspark udf

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have the following code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a: pd.Series):
        self.a = a

    def f(self, b: pd.Series):
        return np.exp(a) + b
```

I also have a Pyspark dataframe with double columns `a` and `b`. I want to run

```py
df.withColumn('c', MyClass(df['a']).f(df['b']))
```

which of course fails. How do I properly adapt the code of `MyClass` to make that work. (Please note that I cannot simply write the function `f` in terms of Pyspark functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a UDF to wrap the class:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a: pd.Series):
        self.a = a
    def f(self, b: pd.Series):
        return np.exp(self.a) + b

@F.pandas_udf('float')
def myClassUDF(a: pd.Series, b: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return MyClass(a).f(b)

df = spark.createDataFrame([[0,1], [0,2]],['a','b'])

df.withColumn('c', myClassUDF('a','b')).show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|2.0|
|  0|  2|3.0|
+---+---+---+
```